# JCrop unfilled selection variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

When I select an image it already opens with a default crop area, which I set using the (setSelect) method, if I confirm the crop without any change in the crop area, the image is saved without the crop causing errors in my database, I guess I'm not populating the JCrop selection variables. I also noticed that it has a method that fills these variables (onSelect: selectcanvas), but it is only called after modifying the crop area.

**Here is my JCrop script**

```
$("#canvas").Jcrop({
   minSize: [45, 45],
   maxSize: [1200, 1200],
   bgColor: 'white',
   bgOpacity: .2,
   setSelect: [150, 150, 50, 50],
   aspectRatio: 1,
   allowSelect: false,
   onSelect: selectcanvas,
   onRelease: clearcanvas,
   boxWidth: crop_max_width,
   boxHeight: crop_max_height,
}, function () {
    jcrop_api = this;
});
   clearcanvas();
}
```

**And the onSelect method**

```
function selectcanvas(coords) {
  prefsize = {
    x: Math.round(coords.x),
    y: Math.round(coords.y),
    w: Math.round(coords.w),
    h: Math.round(coords.h)
  };
}
```

Is there any way to start the variables with some default value?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$("#canvas").Jcrop({
   minSize: [45, 45],
   maxSize: [1200, 1200],
   bgColor: 'white',
   bgOpacity: .2,
   setSelect: [150, 150, 50, 50],
   aspectRatio: 1,
   allowSelect: false,
   onSelect: selectcanvas,
   onRelease: clearcanvas,
   boxWidth: crop_max_width,
   boxHeight: crop_max_height,
}, function () {
    jcrop_api = this;
});
   clearcanvas();
}
```

To this:

```
$("#canvas").Jcrop({
   onChange: selectcanvas,
   onSelect: selectcanvas,
   onRelease: clearcanvas,
   minSize: [45, 45],
   maxSize: [1200, 1200],
   bgColor: 'white',
   bgOpacity: .2,
   setSelect: [150, 150, 50, 50],
   aspectRatio: 1,
   allowSelect: false,
   boxWidth: crop_max_width,
   boxHeight: crop_max_height,
}, function () {
    jcrop_api = this;
});
   clearcanvas();
}
```

This will make sure that your functions are defined first, This will make sure that when a user adds an image to your input the change event will get called and your variables will be initialized.